# Continuous deployment from git using Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-run

I am trying to make a build trigger for Cloud Run using [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build#fully-managed_1),
but I get the following error message:

```
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
Step #0: unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
Finished Step #0
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Does anyone know why?

EDIT: My project repo is split into frontend and backend folders. I am just trying to deploy my backend folder which contains a go api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have followed the tutorial you provided and I encountered the same error message.

It seems like the steps specified inside the `cloudbuild.yaml` file are requiring a `Dockerfile` to be created on the repositories root folder. Precisely, the following instruction is building the image on your `.` folder.

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/[SERVICE-NAME]:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
```

There are two solutions to your problem. If you need build a docker image, simply creating the `Dockerfile` will solve your issue. Another solution would be to not use a custom image. I have used the following `cloudbuild.yaml` file in order to deploy successfully:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args:
  - 'run'
  - 'deploy'
  - '[SERVICE-NAME]'
  - '--image'
  - 'gcr.io/cloudrun/hello'
  - '--region'
  - '[REGION]'
  - '--platform'
  - 'managed'
```

Notice how I'm still using a container image (`gcr.io/cloudrun/hello`).

-- edit

As explained by @guillaume-blaquiere, the tutorial takes for granted that your repository is already working on Cloud Run. You should check a [Cloud Run tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy) before this one.

-- edit 2

A third solution that worked for OP is to specify the path of the `Dockerfile` in the build instruction. That is done by changing the `.` directory for the relative directory that contains the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: @sdfsdf I didn't think of that, I have edited my answer in order to include it.

Answer (score 0):

The error says `/workspace/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

I suppose your repository does not contain a `Dockerfile` at its root.

Comment: Which is weird because the [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/continuous-deployment-with-cloud-build#fully-managed_1) makes no mention of a Dockerfile. Also, the trigger asks for a Dockerfile or a cloudbuild.yaml file and the tutorial covers the cloudbuild.yaml file.

Comment: I agree, the tutorial considers that you already have a working app on Cloud Run and you want to automate the build and deploy. It's not a from scratch tutorial! Look at the first step of cloudbuild.yaml file. It call a docker build command, and Docker look for a Dockerfile (by default). Look here for a tutorial on Cloud Run: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy#go